# Meteor GridFS upload file on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, gridfs

i use meteor gridfs to upload file. i only know to trigger upload using `change` on `input file`. this is my implementation :

```
'change .myFileInput': function (event, template) {
        FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function (file) {
            Images.insert(file, function (err, fileObj) {
                if (err) {

                } else {

                    var userId = Meteor.userId();
                    var imagesURL = {
                        "profile.image": "/cfs/files/images/" + fileObj._id
                    };
                    Meteor.users.update(userId, {$set: imagesURL});
                }
            });
        })
    }
```

but in my condition i need to upload on form submit so far i only create this :

```
<form>
            <div class="panel-body">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">New Photo</label>
                    <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" class="form-control">
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
            </div>
        </form>

'submit': function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        FS.Utility.eachFile(e, function (file) {
            Images.insert(file, function (err, fileObj) {
                    if (err) {

                    } else {

                        var userId = Meteor.userId();
                        var imagesURL = {
                            "profile.image": "/cfs/files/images/" + fileObj._id
                        };
                        Meteor.users.update(userId, {$set: imagesURL});
                    }
                });
        });
    }
```

but nothing happend.
how to upload file on submit using meteor gridfs?